# Dynamically add directive on an element that doesnt exist yet

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/lordfriend/nya-bootstrap-select) to bootstrap my dropdown with angularJS. The issue I'm having is that the code they want looks something to

```
<ol class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="City" name="city" required>

                <li nya-bs-option="city in subCities ">

                    <a>{{ city.name }}</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
```

which then generates something like

```
    <ol ng-model="City" class="nya-bs-select ng-pristine ng-untouched btn-group ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">               
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><span class="pull-left filter-option">- Select -</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu open">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu inner">
            <li><a>- Select -</a></li>
            <li nya-bs-option="city in subCities" class="ng-scope nya-bs-option">
                        <a tabindex="0" class="ng-binding">CityName</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</ol>
```

As you can see it adds a "button" element as a child of `<ol>`. 
How can I "listen" for the "nyaBsSelect" directive so that when it creates the `<button>` element, I want to add a `ng-disabled` directive as the button's attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more directive in the same element as nya-bs-select. That directive can find the button and add the attribute. However as you want to add a directive as attribute you might have to do $compile of button after adding the attribute. You can modify priority so that your directive executes after plugin directive.
I have not looked into the plugin. I guess you could also modify the plugin to add one more attribute and ng disabled to button and bind both.

Comment: i ended up creating another directive and adding the attribute in that directive. Thanks!