# prevent rendering angular attribute directive in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-template

After add some conditional class and attribute binding in the template, angular keep those  attribute directive in the dom when I check in the dev tool like this

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="lsmodal.data.profile.gender" value="male" ng-attr-checked="lsmodal.app.state.isMaleChecked" ng-click="lsmodal.app.meta.selectRadioButton($event, 'male')" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse">
```

this is really hard for me to read visually. How I can stop rendering those directive bindings since I do not need to know how I bind those in dev tool. I just wanna it gives me the vanilla html code like

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to what I asked. You'll have to use $compile to remove those directives. You can see what I asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923058/dynamically-add-directive-on-an-element-that-doesnt-exist-yet)

Answer (score -1):

This code will prevent you to see those classes and attributes:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
   $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

This was introduced in v1.3 so it won't work in lower versions.

Here is a [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) in the documentation for you.

Comment: does OP asked about debugging thing?

Comment: @Guys, sorry to haven't pointed it out exactly, as the documentation explain my answer above will remove the classes and attrs that scopes and bindings creates, regarding with the directives, angular have to have the directives to work, there is no way to remove them.